# Is it possible to run SVN Edge, LAMP and Samba on one server machine?

Tags: linux, samba, lamp, linux-server

I'm looking into building a simple home server for myself. I don't really know a lot about servers but what I'm looking to do is:

- Have a SVN Edge server to store my development projects (I know I can use online repositories but I'd like to do this)
- Install LAMP to host a website
- Install Samba to have a personal file storage system

I was wondering whether it's possible to do all of this from one machine and be able to access it from anywhere with an internet connection. If this is possible, is it the best way to achieve what I want or could anyone suggest a better alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes. Go ahead, install your favorite distro, use the package manager to install all your various servers, and have at it. Samba is often already installed for you.
More important answer: Everything about this is good, except this part: "able to access it from anywhere". You do NOT want to open your home network to this. Use a VPN, or better use an ssh connection.

Comment: Good shout on the VPN or SSH. I'll do that too. Thanks for the answer!